# Embedded UINavigationController Storyboards Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am trying to embed a UINavigationController using a UIViewController with storyboards.

I am trying to "push" RecordViewController to PublishViewController. This doesn't seem to be working at all. It is switching "modally."

PublishViewController => UIViewController with an embedded UINavigationController.

RecordViewController => UIViewController.

What am I doing wrong?

Storyboards Image: http://cl.ly/image/0R27072Y2X08

Switch View Segue Code:

```
#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToPublish"]) {

    PublishViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

}
}
```

Comment: It looks to me as if you're wanting to have a navigation controller as a subview(controller) of your PublishViewController?  Is that actually the case?

Comment: embed your navigation controller in RecordViewController then a push segue to PublishViewController. I don't see any reason why you're embedding navigation controller in publish view controller ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this:
[image: Storyboard]

Record View Controller should be embedded in a navigation controller, an the segue between Record VC and Publish VC should be defined as a push segue, not a modal. Note that the pictogram for a push segue is the one between Record and Publish in the attached image.

Comment: app crashes. any idea why?

Comment: 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'pushToPublish'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: @asdasdasd you are getting this generic exception because your record view controller is not embedded in navigation controller.